# How to implement Autonomous Transaction in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, transactions

I'm trying to implement autonomous transaction in SQL Server 2008 procedure. The procedure will simply have two transaction, nested, on which the `InnerTransaction` will commit but the `OuterTransaction` will be rollback.
I have saw lots of example which implements the reverse processes successfully. But I haven't found any solution for my problem.

sample table scripts

```
create table testTab1(id int identity(1,1) primary key, name varchar(100));
create table testTab2(id int , name varchar(100));
insert into testTab1(name) values('User1'),('User2'),('User3');
```

sample code of procudure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[testSP2]
AS
BEGIN
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON
BEGIN TRAN 
    insert into testTab1(name) values('User4'),('User5'),('User6');
    IF @@ROWCOUNT>0
        BEGIN
            SAVE TRAN InnerTran
                insert into testTab2(id,name) values(1,'User4'),(2,'User5'),(3,'User6');
                --PRINT 'NUMBER OF TRAN='+CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS VARCHAR(5)) 
            COMMIT TRAN InnerTran
        END                 
ROLLBACK
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF
END
```

MY desired Output is

[image]

Comment: Simply put...you can't. Nested transactions are a myth. They do NOT even come to close to what would you think they should. The second transaction only increments the value of @@TRANCOUNT and a rollback or commit sets the count to 0 and does a rollback/commit for each "nested" transaction. http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for your comment, I just want to be sure that if we can do this in Sql server or not using `nested transaction`. But I think now I have to go for another approach to do this. can you suggest any hack for that.

Comment: There is no "hack" for this. Look at your code. It is not logically possible to EVER get to your inner transaction unless you violate a constraint. What are you really trying to do here? Maybe as simple as using NOT EXISTS in your insert to testTab2? Some explanation of the requirements would make this a lot easier.

Comment: @SeanLange don't take the insert statement seriously. I'll replace those insert by some other `dml`. I just want to do `InnerTransaction` will commit but the `OuterTransaction` will be rollback in this proc.

Comment: As I said previously, there is no way to do this. Period. End of story. The real issue though is WHAT are you actually trying to do, because more than likely you just need to think about it differently. Maybe you need to use TRY/CATCH. Then if your insert fails you use the catch to insert somewhere else.

Comment: Oracle of course has this feature and it's called Autonomous Transaction.  I've only been working in the SQL Server world for 1.5 years now and I hate that there's not existing Autonomous Transaction.  That feature was heavily utilized by my code and others on my team when I worked in Oracle for 8+ years.  So annoying when you discover something so simply (In concept) that you've been using for so long but you discover other very similar technologies don't implement these features which you take for granted.

Comment: I'm just watching and waiting for Microsoft to give us the Autonomous Transaction feature which is how I found myself on this SO post.  I look into this maybe once a month.

Answer (score 2):

Another Blog but well written showing each 'hack' to mimic Oracle's wonderful Autonomous Transaction feature.  I look forward to a world where this feature exists in SQL Server.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/how-to-create-an-autonomous-transaction-in-sql-server-2008/ba-p/383471

Note: For some reason when you bring this up to SQL Server folks they look at you like you're crazy and start to ask things like "Why do you need that... why would anybody need that?".  Now that I'm in a SQL Server shop I get this a ton.  Just know that if you came from Oracle... a database that has robust and in depth features such as awesome search algorithms built in and excellent string parsing and manipulation capabilities you will discover after diving into SQL Server that it lacks these features.  Don't get me wrong... SQL Server does many things very well such as Table Variables and Temp Tables as well as just the ability to mix your T-SQL right in line with normal SQL. Oracle separates it's PL-SQL from it's SQL Engine and that is one major drawback to Oracle.  Pro's and Con's.

Comment: Although I've only ever worked with SQL Server, never Oracle, the use case for autonomous transactions comes up every year or two. It would be a really handy feature. For me the main use case is to write to a log table regardless of the outcome of the transaction. If we're in complete control of transactions then we could use variables or table variables (which aren't enrolled in a transaction) to store the data we want to log, and log it after the transaction has been rolled back (or committed). But sometimes a stored proc is enrolled in an outer transaction and still needs to log messages.